# Mongoose schema with Mixed type behaving awkward

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an Event schema declared like this:

```
var EventSchema = new Schema({
  type: String,
  action: String,
  createdAt: { type : Date, default : Date.now },
  payload: {},
});
```

And I'm trying to create a new instance using this hash (other attributes omitted for clarity):

```
{
  "payload": {
    "apikey": {
      "created_at": "2014-07-22T18:35:19.995Z",
      "id": 1,
      "owner_id": 3,
      "owner_type": "User",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "can_create": false,
          "can_delete": false,
          "can_read": false,
          "can_update": false,
          "created_at": "2014-07-22T18:37:18.111Z",
          "id": 3,
          "key": "second",
          "role_id": 1,
          "updated_at": "2014-07-22T18:37:18.121Z"
        },
        {
          "can_create": false,
          "can_delete": false,
          "can_read": false,
          "can_update": false,
          "created_at": "2014-07-22T18:37:18.111Z",
          "id": 2,
          "key": "permission-key-2",
          "role_id": 1,
          "updated_at": "2014-07-22T18:37:18.121Z"
        }
      ],
      "realm_id": 6,
      "realm_type": "Organization",
      "secret": "c35ca06eab38850493bae0f974787587",
      "token": "a9e4691ebc1551b6b1ee2147397248a6",
      "updated_at": "2014-07-22T18:40:26.553Z"
    }
  }
}
```

But instead of saving in the structure I sent, it's saving it like this:

```
{
    "apikey": {
        "created_at": "2014-07-22 18:35:19 UTC",
        "id": "1",
        "owner_id": "3",
        "owner_type": "User",
        "permissions": {
            "can_create": [
                "false",
                "false"
            ],
            "can_delete": [
                "false",
                "false"
            ],
            "can_read": [
                "false",
                "false"
            ],
            "can_update": [
                "false",
                "false"
            ],
            "created_at": [
                "2014-07-22 18:37:18 UTC",
                "2014-07-22 18:37:18 UTC"
            ],
            "id": [
                "3",
                "2"
            ],
            "key": [
                "second",
                "permission-key-2"
            ],
            "role_id": [
                "1",
                "1"
            ],
            "updated_at": [
                "2014-07-22 18:37:18 UTC",
                "2014-07-22 18:37:18 UTC"
            ]
        },
        "realm_id": "6",
        "realm_type": "Organization",
        "secret": "c35ca06eab38850493bae0f974787587",
        "token": "a9e4691ebc1551b6b1ee2147397248a6",
        "updated_at": "2014-07-22 18:40:26 UTC"
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Just tested it myself and it worked fine.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Which version of MongoDB, mongoose, nodejs and/or express are you using?

Comment: MongoDB 2.4.10, mongoose 3.8.8, node 0.10.22. There is nothing about express in your question.

Comment: I may try to do it using your versions of node and mongoose, if you want.